# How to add node modules to cPanel

Tags: cpanel, node-js

I am new to web hosting. I am currently hosting my website on Morse Host.  My website has a menu screen that requires node modules. Uploading them from my computer will take a really long time. Is there a way I can include them in my cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions here - https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

If you don't have SSH access, maybe your hosting tech support can install it for you.

Comment: Node_modules are directories of files I need to upload to my already built website for one specific functionality to work...

Comment: This is a link-only answer. It is not appropriate to require that people click a link to get their answer. It would be better to provide an answer here. Please edit this to summarize the instructions. We are trying to build a repository of knowledge here.   Links often change over time or break. Answers written here are very stable and are likely to be available long-term. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)